# Why EditText is not expanding to fill_parent

Tags: android, android-edittext, fill-parent

I have written an XML code, where I want the EditText to be expanded to fit the parent width. After spending so much time, I can not find a way to expand the EditText.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip">        
        <TextView
            android:text="Comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="3dip" />      
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip">        
       <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="5" 
            android:gravity="top|left" 
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" 
            android:minWidth="10.0dip"
            android:maxWidth="5.0dip"/>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="center">           
       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:text="Next" />       
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

what i have made wrong here. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra colomn of TextView in every row.

This code may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"> 

        <TextView android:text="" />    

        <TextView
            android:text="Comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:padding="3dip" />      
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"> 

        <TextView android:text="" />        

       <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/EditText02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:lines="5" 
            android:gravity="top|left" 
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow 
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView android:text="" />        

       <Button 
            android:id="@+id/cancel"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:text="Next" />       
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

Kind of old, but I believe I have something to add.

I believe that according to the documentation (quoted below) the layout_width and layout_height are pre-determined for all TableRow children.

Instead, the layout_weight can be used to determine the width/height of the elements inside a TableRow. That is, unless you want to set it's android:ems property and give it a width based on it's font size.

For example:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/place"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</TableRow>
```

This produced for me a full-screen wide EditText within a TableRow.

Here's a quote from the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) of TableRow:

> The children of a TableRow do not need to specify the layout_width and
>   layout_height attributes in the XML file. TableRow always enforces
>   those values to be respectively MATCH_PARENT and WRAP_CONTENT.

The problem is, as we know, that in reality it doesn't happen. I suspect layout_width receives "WRAP_CONTENT" as well.

Answer (score 7):

Please add `android:stretchColumns="0"` to your TableLayout

Comment: Awesome!  This is perfect for me!! Thank

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if serious.

You have your EditText's minimum width (`minWidth`) set larger than it's maximum width (`maxWidth`), and you haven't given it a `layout_width` attribute (which you should set to `match_parent`).

Comment: i have given it a layout_width to match_parent, but nothing is changing.

Comment: Also remove `maxWidth` and `minWidth` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the `android:orientation` attribute from the `LinearLayout`

Secondly if this is all what you require, you can avoid using a `TableLayout` and use only a single `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and all the other three `View`s in it.

Comment: The `android:orientation` is not mandatory. It defaults to `horizontal` according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `layout_weight="1"` in edittextview.

Answer (score 0):

`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  -->> change to 0dip
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" -->> change to 0dip
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".StartUp" >`